# .Net6 Entity Frameworks - OData && AutoMapper

Tags: .net, entity-framework, odata, automapper

i am having a OAPIData api controller and using Entity frameworks db context
i have db Entities and for each entity i have its own DTO
so i have CatalogItem with a list of Plans with a list of Offers
and then i have CatalogItemDTO with a list of PlanDTO with a list of OfferDTO

the DTO objects hides some internal [roperties i have on my db entities.
so i need my OData controller to return DTO's objects

when i use auto mapper extensions like Context.CatalogItems.UseAsDataStore(mapper.ConfigurationProvider).For()

I see that the underline SQL query been sent to the SQL server includes the join to all the object graph, so its includes the Plans and offers, no matter if those were selected or not (having the same issue with GraphQL api BTW).

how can i avoid it in a way that if the Plans was not included in the selection list , the plans table will not be joind ?

if i am not using auto mapper projection, its works as expected and the nested object are joined only if they were selected

using ProjectTo instead of UseAsDataStore, is doing the same issue

even in other scenarios, when ever auto mapper is used to map entities to DTO's all the nested objects are been joined in the sql command

Thanks in advnace!

tried UseAsDataStore and also ProjectTo

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion